# Quiero poner una imagen de fondo de pantalla en un div

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap, div

Se que suena raro, pero en mi caso realmente creo que es muy necesario. Lo que debo de hacer es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cuaderno es una imagen y el resto, es un acordeón de Bootstrap.
Mi logica es la mostrada en el codigo, aunque realmente no da ningún tipo de efecto:

```
 /*CSS*/
  <style>
  .cuaderno{
  max-width:350px;
  background-image: url("img/cuaderno.jpeg");
}

</style>
 /*HTML, BOOTSTRAP*/
<div class="cuaderno">
 /*acordeon de bootstrap*/
</div>
```

Este es mi resultado (Osea, no se muestra la imagen que quiero de fondo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi carpeta por si a alguno le interesa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene alguna idea de que puedo hacer?
PD: No pongo todo el acordeon de bootstrap por ser muy largo y porque no lo considero necesario mostrarlo, solo decir que contiene tambien un poco de php.

Muchas gracias por la atención!

Comment: ¿Y que te dice la consola?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Me salta que no tengo unas imagenes que estoy llamando (porque me las tienen que pasar) pero de esta en especifica no dice nada.

Comment: Intenta darle un dándole un alto definido y que tu acordion este centrado verticalmente, me parece que el div esta del mismo tamaño que tu acordion por lo tanto este ultimo lo tapa completamente.

Comment: @dihego08 gracias! Lo voy a probar en estos dias!